# Difference between creating dao object with constructor and by EJB injection

Tags: ejb, ejb-3.0

I would like to know the difference between creating an DAO Object with constructor like :

```
myDaoObject = new MyDaoObject();
```

and creating it by EJB injection :

```
@EJB
MyDaoObject myDaoObject;
```

Is there a difference in the running and/or performance ?
thanks.

Comment: possibly duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7662501/is-it-deemed-bad-practice-to-inject-the-dao-into-the-constructor-and-if-so-why

Comment: You seem to have completely missed the point of EJBs. This is not just like decoration. I suggest to carefully read this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18379228

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well...you really can't create EJBs with constructor because you would lose the functionality offered by the container (dependency injection, pooling, calling of @PostConstruct, transactions, ...). So only correct way is

```
@EJB
MyDaoObject myDaoObject;
```

P.S. Or, in case you are using `CDI`, `@Inject` instead of `@EJB`